# Create an interface which looks similar to settings app

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface

I am trying to create an interface similar to this:

[image: http://0.tqn.com/d/ipod/1/0/h/G/-/-/iphone-music-settings.jpg]

It needs to have text fields and table cells.

Comment: OK, what is your question? So far all you've done is stated a goal. Stackoverflow is for getting help with specific programming questions. Please ask a specific question. What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: I have no idea what interface objects to use, I have tried placing a table view in my view controller and then making it smaller, and placing text fields and labels inside it, but it does not look anything like what I want. I thought that its probable that their is some template or generic way to do this as this is a common interface that is used.

Comment: The screen you posted is using a `UITableViewController` with a "grouped" style. The table is using multiple sections.

Comment: alright thanks I'll see if I can get it working

Comment: Be sure to read the "Table View Programming Guide" in the iOS docs.

Comment: would this still work if used just a table view within a view controller

Comment: Yes it would. It's just a little extra work to get it all hooked up properly. The only reason to do so is because you want other views besides the table view to be shown in the view controller.

Comment: I would create another tableviewcontroller but im not sure how that would interact with my navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That view is basically a `UITableView` with individual `UITableViewCell`s which are customized with the input views.

Take a look at the [UITableView creation example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a UITableViewController with static cells and split it into two sections.

Make sure you check off grouped

Comment: The cells aren't grouped. The table's style is set to "grouped".